# Android ArrayAdapter filter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, filtering, android-arrayadapter

I'm making an android app after i completed the IOS version and running into a problem.

I have an ListView with on top an EditText.
When i enter text into the EditText i filter the items in the ListView.

```
private void setupSearch() {
        EditText inputSearch = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And i successfully filter the items. But now when i tap the item is uses the id 0 because it is the only item in the ListView. But the arrayList has multiple items is not filtert so it will open the item with id 0. Witch is a totally differed item.

Here i setup the ListView:

```
private void setupListview() {
    ArrayList test = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        test.add(list.get(i).getTitle());
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.row, R.id.rowTitleView, test);
    ListView List = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview_faqs);
    List.setAdapter(adapter);
    List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent showNext = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity.class);
            showNext.putExtra("title", list.get(i).getTitle());
            showNext.putExtra("image", list.get(i).getImage());
            getActivity().startActivity(showNext);
        }
    });
}
```

So how do i filter the list of items, or can i use something else. I'm a bit lost.

Comment: are you sure you want to use ArrayAdapter<ArrayList> ???

Comment: @pskink No, i want to filter and i could only find that ArrayAdapter has this function. Android is new for me. I had my own adapter that could fill the list view and get the item on selection

Comment: i think you should first try googling for: arrayadapter example